# Calling a method inside second method from another class C++

Tags: c++, class, object

I am trying to call a method inside of another method from a different class but it is giving me the error "variable deck is not a type name". I am not sure what that means. here is my code:

Cardstub.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "CardList.h";
#include "CardStub.h";
#define Ace  1
#define Jack  11
#define Queen  12
#define King 13
enum Suit { hearts, diamonds, clubs, spades };
void cardlist1(vector<Card1>);
void storeCard() {

int i = 0;
std::vector<Card1> deck(52);
std::vector<Card1> cardlist(52);
int temp;

for (Suit suit = hearts; suit <= spades; suit = Suit(suit + 1))
{
    for (int rank = Ace; rank <= King; rank = rank++)
    {
        deck[i].suit = suit;
        deck[i].rank = rank;
        i++;
    }
}

Card1 * CardList::addToTop(deck); //error is here
  }


int main() {

storeCard();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

CardList.cpp

```
#include "CardList.h"
#include "CardStub.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void CardList::writeFile(FILE* File) {

}
void CardList::readFile(FILE *File) {

}

Card1 *CardList::addToTop(vector<Card1>  deck) {
std::vector<Card1> cardlist(52);
cardlist = deck;
for (int count = 0; count <cardlist.size(); count++)                           
//For Loop to Display All Products
{
    //cout << cardlist[count].rank << "\n" << cardlist[count].suit;
}
for (int i = 0; i < cardlist.size(); i++) {
    if (cardlist[i].rank == 2)
        cout << "Two ";
    else if (cardlist[i].rank == 3)
        cout << "Three ";
    else if (cardlist[i].rank == 4)
        cout << "Four ";
    else if (cardlist[i].rank == 5)
        cout << "Five ";
    else if (cardlist[i].rank == 6)
        cout << "Six ";
    else if (cardlist[i].rank == 7)
        cout << "Seven ";
    else if (cardlist[i].rank == 8)
        cout << "Eight ";
    else if (cardlist[i].rank == 9)
        cout << "Nine ";
    else if (cardlist[i].rank == 10)
        cout << "Ten ";
    else if (cardlist[i].rank == 11)
        cout << "Jack ";
    else if (cardlist[i].rank == 12)
        cout << "Queen ";
    else if (cardlist[i].rank == 13)
        cout << "King ";
    else if (cardlist[i].rank == 1)
        cout << "Ace ";
    cout << "of ";
    if (cardlist[i].suit == clubs)
        cout << "Clubs\n";
    else if (cardlist[i].suit == diamonds)
        cout << "Diamonds\n";
    else if (cardlist[i].suit == hearts)
        cout << "Hearts\n";
    else if (cardlist[i].suit == spades)
        cout << "Spades\n";
   }
}
/*
ICard* CardList::remove(int index) {

}

ICard* CardList::removeFromTop() {

}*/
```

CardStub.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define Ace  1
#define Jack  11
#define Queen  12
#define King 13

using namespace std;




struct Card1
{

    Card1() {};
    int rank;
    Suit suit;

    Card1(Suit s, int rank) {};

};
#endif
```

CardList.h

```
#if !defined(CARDLIST_H)
#define CARDLIST_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "CardStub.h"

class CardList {
public:

virtual void writeFile(FILE *File) = 0;
virtual void readFile(FILE *File) = 0;
virtual Card1 * addToTop(vector<Card1> ) = 0;
//virtual ICard* remove(int index) = 0;
//virtual ICard* removeFromTop() = 0;
//public:
//virtual void removeCard(ICard*) = 0;
//virtual void add(ICard*) = 0;

};
#endif
```

The error is in the CardStub.cpp, why exactly does this error appear?

Comment: why a lot of `if`s when you can just use `switch`, or even better, a lookup table?

Comment: `CardList::addToTop` is not a `static` method. You need to invoke it on a `CardList` instance. Other than that, unable to reproduce. Too many other errors.

Comment: Recommend cracking the textbook and reading up on what a pure virtual function is and when you should use one.

Comment: You don't need semicolons at the end of include statements.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a variable name in that line, so it looks like a function declaration rather than a function call. It's expecting `deck` to be the type of the parameter.

You have other problems too, pay attention to the comments others have left.